Calculate difference of values in specific range of time in Excel

In this Google Sheet, i want to calculate the difference of weight between specific time (find the value of weight between 20:55 until 21:05 time o'clock and calculate difference with the last entry of the weight)
In my case must be : 477.93 - 437.97 = 39.96
Must say that this google sheet updated every day in several times
***update!
the solution is on this formula  :
=map(B2:B, C2:C, lambda(time, weight,
if(isbetween(time, value("20:55"), value("21:05")),
weight - offset(C2,counta(C3:C99999),0,1,1),
iferror(ø)
)
))
THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The titles of the question and the screenshot mention Excel. Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states "Do NOT use with [excel]" and the [excel] tag description explicitly states "Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]." Choose one platform and edit the question appropriately.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

I do apologize, can you please clarify how you are referring to your Dummy Data with your actual goal? Your example doesn't make any sense with your data, I understand the weight differences, however Datestamps and Timestamps doesn't make sense how do you choose which one to be used for computation can you clarify this part?

Clear column I2:I and put a formula that uses map() and offset() in cell I2, like this:
=map(B2:B, C2:C, lambda(time, weight, 
  if(isbetween(time, value("20:55"), value("21:05")), 
    weight - offset(weight, -1, 0), 
    iferror(ø) 
  ) 
))

See map() and offset().

It is unclear what you mean by "last entry of weight." Perhaps you are referring to the figure from the previous day, or the most recent previous day where data exists for the time span you mention? Please edit the question and clarify the issue there. Also follow the instructions in the comments therein.

google sheet with solution
the solution is in this formula :
=map(B2:B, C2:C, lambda(time, weight, if(isbetween(time, value("20:55"), value("21:05")), weight - offset(C2,counta(C3:C99999),0,1,1), iferror(ø) ) ))

thank you so much!!!

How is this answer different from the already accepted answer ?
